# Why does metalization occur at the end of the semiconductor manufacturing process?

Tags: semiconductor

I recently completed a semiconductor fabrication lab for university and metioned that the metalization stage was performed at the end of the process in fab labs, unlike in teaching labs where it was done earlier. I'm curious about the reasoning behind this difference in the lab process flow.

Comment: Without explicitly explaining what you mean by "done earlier" this question can not be answered. Done earlier **than what**?